# making 2 new arrays of balls from a created array of balls in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am currently writing a Java pool game applet in Eclipse. I have declared an array of 16 balls at the start of my applet and which deals in the start() method with positioning all balls as follows:

```
Ball b[] = new Ball[16];

public void start()
{
b[0] = new Ball(200,425,0,0);
b[1] = new Ball(200, 140, 0, 0);
b[2] = new Ball(190, 120, 0, 0);
b[3] = new Ball(210, 120, 0, 0);
b[4] = new Ball(180, 100, 0, 0);
b[5] = new Ball(200, 100, 0, 0);
b[6] = new Ball(220, 100, 0, 0);
b[7] = new Ball(170, 80, 0, 0);
b[8] = new Ball(190, 80, 0, 0);
b[9] = new Ball(210, 80, 0, 0);
b[10] = new Ball(230, 80, 0, 0);
b[11] = new Ball(160, 60, 0, 0);
b[12] = new Ball(180, 60, 0, 0);
b[13] = new Ball(200, 60, 0, 0);
b[14] = new Ball(220, 60, 0, 0);
b[15] = new Ball(240, 60, 0, 0);
}
```

These balls are coloured with b[0] being the cue ball, b[5] being the black ball and the other balls being either red or yellow depending on their positions within the triangle.

What I need to do is to make another 2 arrays from the original array the first of which will be just the red balls e.g. b[1], b[3], b[4]..... and so on. The second of which will be just the yellow balls e.g. b[2], b[6], b[7]..... and so on.

What I am wondering is whether or not it is possible to make 2 arrays of a single array taking just the values of the red and yellow balls? And if so how and what would be the most efficient way of writing these arrays?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where in the code is it written that b[i] is black/red/yellow?

Comment: How about starting by adding a property specifying a balls' color?

Comment: 'b[0] = new Ball(200,425,0,0, "White");'  So now it reads.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you seem not to be very experienced, the aim of the question makes perfect sense. You don't need to create new Ball instances, just get the ones from the array previously defined:

```
Ball reds[] = new Ball[7];
Ball yellows[] = new Ball[7];

for(int i=1;i<b.length;i++) {
  if(i!=5) {
    if(i%2==0) {
      yellows[i/2-1]=b[i];
    } else {
      reds[i<5?(i/2):(i/2-1)]=b[i];
    }
  }
}
```

This iterates through the balls, from index 1 to 15, and we leave out number 5, and depending on the remainder of the loop variable divided by two.

**EDIT** hey, this is not that straightforward as it seemed first, leaving out the ball no 5 requires some tricks to be made...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your right I'm not very experienced still learning the ropes. I've added in the code you entered above. I was just wondering if the code above has the tricks you mentioned for leaving out ball no 5? It is a little difficult now to be fair. Would it be better to change the value of the black ball to no 15 maybe and have the length in the for loop at <=14?

Comment: I have updated the code for for my start() method which now contains the colour of the balls once the game starts.

Comment: 'b[0] = new Ball(200,425,0,0, "White");'